# Why return getElementsBy** not working?

Tags: javascript, function

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="ul-id">
<li>Text Content</li>  
<li>Text Content</li>  
<li>Text Content</li>  
<li>Text Content</li>  
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function getId(idname) {return document.getElementById(idname);} // with document at first
```

```
function getTag(tagname) {return getElementsByTagName(tagname);} // witout document at first
```

**Results:**
When i call it with:

```
getId("ul-id").innerHTML // this code is working fine
```

```
getId("ul-id").getTag("li").length // not working
```

```
document.getElementById("ul-id").getTag("li").length // this also not working
```

Can you tell me the reason and how to fix it ? ^_^

Comment: There is no `getTag` method...

Comment: there is no `getElementsByTagName` function. it should be [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: @Tyr, __Disagree:(__

Comment: That's absolutely not true @Tyr

Comment: Thats your opinion. ;)

Comment: even today I use only js, never jquery... so, I support @Rayon comment 100% ... especially when I see someone use jquery for some basics, disaster. sorry, but it's true. people will forgot basics.

Comment: @tyr, jquery is so huge library. I think so many of jquery feature i never use and i just want to run codes i used only.

Comment: @Rayon, can you tell me to make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to add a custom method on elements in the DOM, you need to extend the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) prototype to add the method.

In that case the method chaining works as follows:

```js
function getId(idname) {
  return document.getElementById(idname);
}

Element.prototype.getTags = function getNestedElements(tagName) {
  return this.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
};


Element.prototype.getTag = function getNestedElements(tagName) {
  return this.getTag(tagName)[0];
};


document.write(
  getId('ul-id').getTags('li').length
);
```

```html
<ul id="ul-id">
  <li>Text Content</li>  
  <li>Text Content</li>  
  <li>Text Content</li>  
  <li>Text Content</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: I suppose it will just create redundancy of methods.. As `Element.getElementsByTagName` proto is there why to write our own ? I would rather suggest `querySelectorAll` as better alternate for all of this...

Comment: @Rayon That is exactly why I started the answer with an *if* statement.

Comment: @Rayon I am a big fan of `querySelectorAll` as well, but it is slightly slower than chaining the `getElement*` methods :)

Comment: Easier things are quiet slower :P

Answer (score 3):

You can't invoke `getTag` on `getId`. 
You can solve this problem by doing this kind of workaround:

```
function getTag(context, tagname) {
  return context.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45z8ccc1/).

Comment: good answer but need some modification... for example `getTag('ul-id','li');` will not work. need to check is `context` an object or string, or, even, nothing... that would be nice completed usefull function :-) +1

Comment: Yeap. I was only showing the way not final solution. Te best way will be to build object when you can chaining methods like `myLib.getId("ul-id").getTag("li")`. But at the end of a day You will build pure jQuery replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('ul-id');
var b = a.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
console.log(b);
```

Comment: A nice little explanation will help future users :)

Comment: Yes it would be helpful for future users :)

Answer (score 0):

`getId` and `getTag` are just functions. You can't simply chain it. Try to use the DOM apis directly.

```
document.getElementById("ul-id").getElementsByTagName("li").length
```